# Netezza Box reboots when following query is executed

Tags: sql, netezza

When I run the following query, my Netezza NPS reboots. Would someone please let me know what is causing this behaviour?

````sql
select avg ( bse.WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR ) as g_AVG
, sqlext.median( bse.WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR )  as g_med
 from (
 select WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR
 FROM (

         select distinct  LOYALTY_ACCOUNT_CARD_ID
        , BONUS_END_DATE
        ,  LAG(BONUS_END_DATE,1) OVER (partition by LOYALTY_ACCOUNT_CARD_ID order by BONUS_END_DATE) as PRIOR_BONUS_END_DATE
        ,(( BONUS_END_DATE - PRIOR_BONUS_END_DATE)/7) as WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR

          from JO_ACT_PTD_STEP_1 bse
          where upper (  bonus_desc ) like '%SPEND%'
          and redemption = 1
  ) BSE

  where   WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR is not null  and WEEKS_BETWEEN_RESPONSES_HR > 0
  ) bse limit 500 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the support people at IBM
There is probably a stack trace or a dump file somewhere that will tell them what happened
If I was experiencing your problem I would remove each of the function calls one by one and make the sql simpler and simpler until the error disappeared
But of course you will need to do that in the middle of the night or at a time when nobody else is being bothered by the constant re-boots